# Make constexpr array of function values

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming, c++17

I have a function `f(i, j)` that accepts two `std::size_t` arguments and I want to make a `constexpr std:array` out of its values on a 2d grid, `(i = 0, ..., rows-1; j = 0, ..., cols-1)` in, say, column-major order.

The code:

```
#include <array>
#include <tuple>
#include <type_traits>

template<std::size_t rows, std::size_t cols>
constexpr auto make_2d_index_table()
{
    std::array<std::array<std::size_t, 2>, rows * cols> table{};
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < table.size(); ++i)
        table[i] = {i % rows, i / rows};

    return table;
}

template<std::size_t rows, std::size_t cols, class Func>
constexpr std::array<std::invoke_result_t<Func, std::size_t, std::size_t>, rows * cols> 
    make_array_of_2d_func_values(Func&& func)
{
    return apply([&func](auto... row_col)
    {
        return std::array<std::invoke_result_t<Func, std::size_t, std::size_t>, rows * cols>
            {std::apply(std::forward<Func>(func), row_col)...};
    }, make_2d_index_table<rows, cols>());
}
```

Usage:

```
constexpr auto arr = make_array_of_2d_func_values<5, 3>(
    [](auto i, auto j) { return i + 2 * j; });
```

The object of the type returned by a function may not be default constructible. So I can't just create an `array<invoke_result_t<...>, rows * cols> arr{}` of default constructed objects and then initialize it in the `for` loop like in `make_index_table()`.

Is this a good solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of creating an array of tuples, it may be simpler to use `std::make_index_sequence()` to create an array of (1-dimensional) indexes, and decompose those into arrays and columns at the point where the function is actually called.

Doing that allowed me to eliminate the `for` loop:

```
#include <array>
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

template<std::size_t stride, class Func, std::size_t... i>
constexpr auto make_elements(Func&& func, std::index_sequence<i...>)
{
    using result_type = std::invoke_result_t<Func, std::size_t, std::size_t>;
    return std::array<result_type, sizeof...(i)>
        { func(i % stride, i / stride)... };
}

template<std::size_t rows, std::size_t cols, class Func>
constexpr auto make_array_alternative(Func&& func)
{
    return make_elements<rows>(std::forward<Func>(func),
                               std::make_index_sequence<rows*cols>());
}
```

This still involves two tightly-coupled functions.  I managed to use `std::apply()` again to get it down to one function and a helper:

```
#include <array>
#include <tuple>
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

template<std::size_t... I>
constexpr auto
tuple_of_sequence(std::index_sequence<I...>)
{
    return std::make_tuple(I...);
}

template<std::size_t rows, std::size_t cols, class Func>
constexpr auto
make_array_alternative(Func&& func)
{
    using result_array = std::array<std::invoke_result_t<Func, std::size_t, std::size_t>, rows*cols>;
    return std::apply([&func](auto... i){ return result_array{func(i % rows, i / rows)...}; },
                      tuple_of_sequence(std::make_index_sequence<rows*cols>()));
}
```

---

In case it's useful, my test program to compare my alternative implementation with the original is:

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    auto const f = [](auto row, auto col) { return row + 10 * col; };
    auto const print = [](auto arr) {
        for (auto i: arr)
            std::cout << i << ' ';
        std::cout << std::endl;
    };

    print(make_array_of_2d_func_values<5, 3>(f));
    print(make_array_alternative<5, 3>(f));
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I like your solution, it is much more clear.

Answer (score 3):

One simple improvement: the return type of `make_array_of_2d_func_values()` can be `auto`, to save writing `std::array<std::invoke_result_t<Func, std::size_t, std::size_t>, rows * cols>` twice.

I think you may be able to specialize `std::tuple_size` and `std::get` for the index table so that it doesn't require any storage even when invoked with non-constexpr arguments; I'm still experimenting but expect an update to this answer!

Comment: In case it's not obvious - the "update" is posted as a new answer!